# CSS loading fonts from internet

Tags: html, css, css-frameworks

I'm using **foundation.min.css** in my project.
Every time I load the above in my HTML file, my browser tries to fetch the fonts online.
But the strange part is that it works even if there's no internet access.

I need to know:

1. How to disable foundation from fetching the fonts online?
2. Why there's no change in functionality even if it gets loaded?

> How to edit this to remove online fetching functionality without harming the original file? foundation.min.css code:

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700");
```

> HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-csp>
  <head>
    <link href="styles/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>

<div>
        <div>
        <h3>Sample Application</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Your text here..">
        <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
<button>Submit</button>
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age as on 1/1/2014</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Sourabh Sharma</td><td>21</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Shourya Sharma</td><td>23</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Vinay Kumar</td><td>18</td></tr>
</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be, if I figure out how to edit the css which is providing a particular link to fetch that data, I can remove it and have a solution to this problem? or not?

Comment: Are you using @fontface or Google webfonts ?

Comment: no, I've just included the foundation.min.css. Wait, I'll upload my HTML too

Comment: It seems they are using google web fonts, If you want you can remove it. It works locally because you have pre-installed that font. It wont work on other's system if they don't have the font.

Comment: removed that and still works :)

Comment: Don't forget to test it with other system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your offline, removing the web-font import will not prevent the font from displaying if you have the font on your computer.  It will only prevent the font from displaying if its viewed by someone who doesn't have the font installed.

If at some point you plan to use the fonts then leave the @import alone and just add an override that you can easily toggle on and off.

```
body { font-family:arial,sans-serif !important; }
```

If you only want to affect specific fonts and not the entire document then just search and replace in your editor of choose for the font-family declaration you want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

> How to disable foundation from fetching the fonts online?

remove the following code from foundation.min.css (you've mentioned above)

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700");
```

> Why there's no change in functionality even if it gets loaded?

because it describes the required css locally